# Doubts in first lemma in the paper of Adams regarding sharp Moser inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, elliptic-pde

This question is on a point in D.R. Adams paper "A Sharp Inequality of J. Moser for Higher Order Derivatives". Precisely the lemma says:
Given $a(s,t)$ be a non negative measureable function on $(-\infty,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$ such that
$$
a(s,t)\leq 1\;\text{ when }\;0<s<t\label{1}\tag{1}
$$ and
$$
\sup_{t>0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_t^{\infty} a(s,t)^q ds\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}=b<\infty\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
Then there is a constant $c_0=c_0(p,b)$ such that if $\phi\geq 0$ and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(s)^p ds\leq 1\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
then
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-F(t)} dt\leq c_0
$$
where
$F(t)=t-\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}a(s,t)\phi(s) ds\right)^q$ and
$q=\frac{p}{p-1}$.

1. He claims that
   $$
   \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-F(t)}dt = \int_{\infty}^{\infty}|E_{\lambda}|e^{-\lambda}d\lambda
   $$ where $E_{\lambda}:=\{t\geq 0:F(t)\leq\lambda\}$. I don't see how to prove it. I was thinking of the Layer cake representation but I couldn't prove it as the integral in R.H.S is over $\mathbb{R}$ not in $(0,\infty)$.
2. Furthermore he claims that if $t\in E_{\lambda}$ then
   $$
   t-\lambda\leq((b^q+t)^{\frac{1}{q}}(1-L(t)^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}+bL(t))^q
   $$
   where $L(t)=\left(\int_s^{\infty}\phi(s)^p ds\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ (here the 1st term of RHS comes out from using Holder inequality and equations \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, but the last portion i.e $+bL(t)$ is not coming rather some weaker estimate is coming.

Any help would be very much helpful to understand the thing going on.

Comment: Which paper is it?

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1971445.pdf&hl=en&sa=T&oi=ucasa&ct=usl&ei=fU5MY-eJEoWOygT4u564DQ&scisig=AAGBfm0fNTgczBANrMSPtTkwMCRfrOW_ag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second, rewrite $F(t) \leq \lambda$ as
$$t - \lambda \leq \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} a(s,\,t)\phi(s)\,ds\right)^q,$$
which reduces the problem to showing that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} a(s,\,t)\phi(s)\,ds \leq (b^q + t)^{1/q}(1-L^p(t))^{1/p} + bL(t).$$
To verify this inequality write the left side as
$$\int_{-\infty}^t a(s,\,t)\phi(s)\,ds + \int_t^{\infty}a(s,\,t)\phi(s)\,ds,$$
and apply Holder's inequality to each term. The second term is clearly bounded by $bL(t)$. For the first, use that $\int_{-\infty}^t \phi^p \leq 1-L^p(t)$ (this uses $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi^p \leq 1$) and that $\int_{-\infty}^t a^q(s,\,t) = \int_{-\infty}^0 a^q + \int_0^t a^q  \leq b^q + t$ (using the definition of $b$ for the first, and the bound of $1$ on $a$ in the relevant interval for the second).

Comment: Thank you Professor Mooney for all your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\la\lambda$To answer your first question, write
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|E_\la|e^{-\la}\,d\la
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\la}\,d\la\int_0^\infty dt\,1(F(t)\le\la)
=\int_0^\infty dt\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\la}\,d\la\,1(F(t)\le\la)
=\int_0^\infty dt\,\int_{F(t)}^\infty e^{-\la}\,d\la
=\int_0^\infty dt\,e^{-F(t)},$$
as desired.

Comment: Damm just Fubini thinking about so many things