# Riesz energy for open sets in dimension $1$

Tags: integration, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

This is a continuation of the question [Calculation of Riesz energy for balls](https://mathoverflow.net/q/451961/493060) . As there are three questions,;I am posting a new question here. Riesz energy for a ball $B(x_0,r)$ is given by
$$I_s(B(x_0,r))=\int_{|x-x_0|<r}\int_{|y-x_0|<r}|x-y|^{-s}\ dx\ dy=C_{d,s}r^{2d-s}$$ as in the last post. My question concerns about finding Riesz energy in open sets in dimension $1$.

1. So, in dimension $d=1$ any open set is countable union of disjoint open intervals for example if **I take finite union of open intervals say $U=\cup_{i=1}^{n}\{|x-x_i|<r\}$ where for the simplification let us assume $r$ is fixed. Then calculating $I_s(U)$ can I write
   $I_s(U)=\sum_{i,j=1}^nI_s(|x-x_i|<r,|y-y_j|<r)$ then how to calculate $I_s(|x-x_i|<r,|y-y_j|<r)$? If we use  the transform $x=x_i+ru$ and $y=y_j+rv$ then $|x-y|^{-s}= |(x_i-y_j)+r(u-v)|^{-s}$ but there would be many cross terms in this case, then how to find exact power of $r$ like $r^{2d-s}$ in this case?

Any reply would be very much helpful for my understanding.

Comment: 1. is wrong. (Your double summation somehow does not factor in $x_j$?) It is not too hard to see that the correct expression is $$I_s(U) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n \int_{|x - x_i| < r, |y - x_j| < r} |x - y|^{-s} ~dx~dy $$ which is not equal to what you wrote. // 2. for the countable case, as in the summation every summand is positive, convergence implies absolute and unconditional convergence, so taking $n\to \infty$ as you said would work, provided you use the correct formula for the finite sum. // 3. Using the correct formula extending to the case of $r_i$ is trivial (just insert $i,j$ apropriately

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand what you wrote but say for some $i,j$ which are different how to calculate $I_s(U)$  like the transform last answer used was $x=x_i+ru$ and $y=y_j+rv$ then $|x-y|^{-s}=|(x_i-y_j)+r(u-v)|^{-s}$ but now when we try to expand it there would be cross terms of $r$, then how to get the exact power of $r$?

Comment: I have edited the question appropriately. Please find it. My main concern was initially also how to find the integral when such cross terms occur? How to get an exact $r$ power as above.

Comment: According to a MathOverflow policy, there should be only one question in one post. You seem to have at least three questions here.

Comment: In fact I have seen many questions where multiple questions are there for  example   https://mathoverflow.net/q/432571/493060 and many other PDE questions. That’s why I merged all the questions as they are interlinked . Anyway now I have deleted the other two. But I have seen many questions with multiple sub parts,

Answer (score 1):

**Your assumption that there is an exact power is unwarranted.**
Just compute for a simple case where there are two intervals $(-1-r,-1+r) \cup (1-r, 1+r)$ with $r\in (0,1)$. Its Riesz energy can be expanded to read

$$ I_s = \int_{-r}^r \int_{-r}^r |-1 + w + 1 - z|^{-s} + |-1 + w - 1 - z|^{-s} + |1+w + 1 - z|^{-s} + |1 + w - 1 - z|^{-s} ~dw ~dz $$

which you simplify to be

$$ I_s = 2 \int_{-r}^r \int_{-r}^r |w-z|^{-s} + |2 + w - z|^{-s} ~dw ~dz $$

The first term integrates to $C r^{2-s}$ since it is **twice** the Riesz energy of the interval $(-r,r)$. The second term however does not integrate to a pure power of $r$. For the sake of completeness, let's evaluate it explicitly: noting that $w,z\in (-r,r)$ which is a strict subset of $(-1,1)$, we see that $2 + w-z > 0$, so we can drop the absolute value sign.
$$ \int_{-r}^r \int_{-r}^r (2 + w - z)^{-s} ~dw ~ dz = C' \int_{-r}^r (2 + r - z)^{1-s} - (2 - r - z)^{1-s} ~dz $$
$$ = C'' [ (2- 2r)^{2-s} - 2^{2-s} - 2^{2-s} + (2+2r)^{2-s} ] \tag{1}$$
This is a smooth, even function of $r$, and as $s$ is not an integer, does not reduce to a polynomial. Its leading order term is of size $r^2$, but it also has $r^4$ and higher order terms. As you can see, the "cross" terms vanish faster as $r\to 0$.

---

In general, if you have a finite list of points $\{x_I\}_{I\in \{1, \ldots, n\}}$,   and set $U_r = \cup (x_I - r, x_I+r)$, then the same phenomenon holds: its Riesz energy, can be split into the "diagonal (self-interaction)" part and the "cross terms". The diagonal part (assuming the subintervals don't overlap) can be seen to be the $n$ times the Riesz energy of the $(-r,r)$ interval, once for each subinterval. The cross terms will vanish to order $r^2$. And therefore, in the limit as $r\to 0$, we have the asymptotics

$$ I_s(U_r) = \underbrace{n I_s((-r,r))}_{= O(r^{2-s})} + O(r^2)$$

---

You may also wonder about the case when the radii are different. Again, assuming finitely many points as the radii chosen so that the corresponding intervals $(x_I - r_I, x_I + r_I)$ are pairwise disjoint, you can again split the integration into the diagonal terms plus cross terms. The diagonal terms can be evaluated explicitly to be

$$ \sum_{I= 1}^n I_s((-r_I, r_I)) = C \sum_{I = 1}^n (r_I)^{2-s}$$

The cross terms can be seen to have order

$$ O( \sum_{I\neq J} r_I r_J ) $$

as the vector $(r_1, \ldots, r_n) \to (0,0,\ldots, 0)$, and in particular the leading order behavior is given by the diagonal terms. (For the cross interaction between $(x_I-r_I,x_I+r_I)$ and $(x_J - r_J,x_J+r_J)$, you are looking at the integral
$$ \int_{-r_I}^{r_I} \int_{-r_J}^{r_J} |x_J - x_I + w - z|^{-2s} ~dw ~dz $$
which you can evaluate in a similar fashion as equation (1), using the fact that the non-intersection of the intervals guarantee $x_J - x_I + w - z$ is signed.)